# Format currency using a ISO 4217 code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, internationalization, windows-phone

It is quite simple to format currency according language/country code:

```cs
double money = 9.99;
var formatted = money.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("sv-SE"));
```

This will get the desired result (9,99 kr). However, what I want is to format using a [ISO 4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) code.
There is a [RegionInfo.ISOCurrencySymbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.isocurrencysymbol.aspx) property but I find no method to list all regions/cultures that is available on Windows Phone.

So, is there a way to format currency using a ISO 4217 code on Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes) Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var ciList = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
```